# Expected number of times a random walk of n steps starting from origin and ending at x passes a point

Tags: probability, random-walk

I wonder what is the expected number of times a random walk of n steps starting from origin and ending at x passes a point m located between 0 and x or after x? I just found the occupancy equation and probability of return to the origin and no similar question.

Answer (score 3):

Let $W(x,n)$ be the number of walks of $n$ steps producing a net displacement of $x$ (equivalently, starting at $0$ and ending at $x$).

$$W(x,n)={n \choose \frac{x+n}{2}} \quad [x=n \pmod 2]\,[-n \le x \le n]$$

Let $Z_t$ be the indicator variable of the event "a random walk of $n$ steps starting at $0$ and ending at $x$ is found at position $m$ at step $t$".
Then $$ P(Z_t=1)=E(Z_t)=\frac{W(m,t)W(x-m,n-t)}{W(x,n)}$$

Then, by linearty of expectations, the desired result is

$$ E(\sum_{t=0}^{n-1} Z_t) =\sum_{t=0}^{n-1} \frac{W(m,t)W(x-m,n-t)}{W(x,n)} $$

Comment: Wow, thank you. It seems working! But still don't know how you came up with such an answer? Could you please explain the interpretation of the nominator?

Comment: You mean the expression of $W(x,n)$? That's quite easy to derive and appears in any exposition of random walks, eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk

Comment: I know the meaning of $W(x,n)$. It is the probability of reaching $x$ from origin after $n$ steps. I want the explanation for the following expression: $\Sigma_{t=0}^{n-1} W(m,t)W(x-m,n-t)$.

Comment: My second equation is the ratio of the number of "paths that start at $0$,  cross $m$ at step $t$ and reach $x$ at step $n$" divided by the number of "paths that start at $0$and reach $x$ at step $n$". That is, probability of success=favourable cases over total cases (assuming all equiprobable, as they are if we have a fair random walk).

Comment: Do you have any idea of how I can find the number of paths with 1 cross, 2 crosses and so on over m? I figured out $W(m-1,t)W(2,2)W(x-(m+1),n-t-2)$ for total number of paths with 1 cross but I can't generalize it more crosses.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be a sum of scalar products on the power series of the random walks Markov matrix. $$(p_{x|x-1} {\bf \delta_{x-1}} ^T + p_{x|x+1} {\bf \delta_{x+1}} ^T) \sum_{k=0}^\infty {\bf P}^k [1,0,0,\cdots]^T$$

Where the Dirac delta vectors are $(\delta _i)_j = \cases{1 , i=j\\0,  i \neq j}$

and the $p_{x|x-1},p_{x|x+1}$ can be extracted from the matrix.